# pass string to socat inside a script

Tags: bash, debian, socat

I'm trying to create a script that fires a connection string at an application, so I can record the result.

e.g. can I successfully connect and login to my application.

From the commandline I can run:

```
conRes=$(echo -e -n "\0\x1\x01\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0" | socat STDIO tcp4:127.0.0.1:12345)
```

and then check the result of `${conRes}`

If I watch my application at the time, I can see the connection being made, the connection string being applied, and then the disconnect.

However, once I put it into a script, it stops working.

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
    conRes=$(echo -e -n "\0\x1\x01\x0\x0\x0\x0\x0" | socat STDIO tcp4:127.0.0.1:12345)
    if [ "${conRes}" != "" ]; then
        echo "conRes Successful: ${conRes}"
    else
        echo "conRes Failed"
    fi
```

Looking on my application I can see the connection and disconnection, but there is no sign of the connection string being sent.

Is there something else I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I can answer my own question.

My problem appears to be that I was calling the script using:

```
sh test1.sh
```

By simply changing this and calling

```
./test1.sh
```

it appears to be working. . .